QuickFIX/n Stuck on Session.SendToTarget(message, sessionId)
We are experiencing an issue with our QuickFIX/n client application, where it gets stuck when sending thousands of messages continuously. The problem occurs when the application is simultaneously sending messages and receiving responses from the acceptor. It specifically hangs on the Session.SendToTarget(message, sessionId) call. This issue frequently arises in our Staging environment but works fine in other environments.
How to reproduce:
foreach (var message in messages) // Collection container around 20k messages
{
    Session.SendToTarget(message, sessionId);
}

We will be receiving acknowledge response and other auto responses from our simulated responder as we send messages. After sending around 10k message, application get stuck randomly and stays for hours. Unless we restart application or simulator.
We thought it was causing due to deadlock issue reported in QuickFIX/n package version 1.10.0. We upgraded to use 1.11.2 and still the issue persists. Can anyone help?
Update:
We updated only our client application to use the latest version of QuickFIX. The simulator application, which was responding to the client app, was still using an old version (1.10.0) of QuickFIX/n. Updating the simulator to the latest version of the library solved the hang issue. I tested it multiple times with 50,000 orders, and we can handle requests without getting stuck.

Is that foreach block being called from within an OnMessage() handler, or inside any other QF/n callback?

No. It's called from outside.

So it's definitely not running on the QF event thread?

@GrantBirchmeier An update on the above issue: We updated only our client application to use the latest version of QuickFIX. The simulator application, which was responding to the client app, was still using an old version (1.10.0) of QuickFIX/n. Updating the simulator to the latest version of the library solved the hang issue. I tested it multiple times with 50,000 orders, and we can handle requests without getting stuck.

Do you have the whole stacktrace where it indicates the deadlock?
